# Interface "Interop\Container\ContainerInterface" not found on running any composer command

Tags: composer-php

Running any composer command throws the following error:

```
In ServiceLocatorInterface.php line 16:
                                                              
  [Error]                                                     
  Interface "Interop\Container\ContainerInterface" not found
```

Need any workaround on this

Comment: Create a new user on your machine, reboot the machine, log in with the new user, install composer for that user then report back if the error persists.

Comment: Please share more details. This sounds like a problem with your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem of incorrect installation most probably. I ended up deleting the directory that's supposed to have the files and ran composer install.